# How to add content to Wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress

When I create a new page.... I want to write some text on it in a box... But when I will fill in the box on the Add new page tab it doesn't show up. Where has it gone and how to I get it to appear?

[image]
This must be so stupidly easy, but I can't understand why it doesn't appear. Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you saying the Page itself doesn't appear? Or just the content? To clarify, are you able to click the View Page button (under your title) and see everything as it's supposed to appear, but you're just not able to navigate to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have selected the page template - Blog modern layout. Try set the template to default because it might be a problem with the blog template.

Answer (score 0):

To show up the page content 
After writing it
Just press on **update button** in the left
[image]

Comment: On the left?  This is the page it's supposed to go on but nothing shows up: http://www.hicengineering.com/?page_id=74

Comment: Ok, that's the right. I have done that anyway but the text doesn't appear. I'm guessing it must have something to do with my particular theme: duotive three

Answer (score 0):

Some themes will only display posts set in a certain category on certain pages (such as the homepage). From the description on themeforest.net (see [How can I create the portfolio navigation (filtering) ?](http://themeforest.net/item/duotive-three-complete-wordpress-template/faq/232555)), I think the theme you're using needs specific categories for portfolio browsing to work.